# Sharing Authentication/Data from Rails to Phoenix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, phoenix-framework

#### Background

I have a fairly typical Rails application, which uses Devise for authentication management. While building this app, I realized that realtime chat would be a great feature to have. Ideally, of course, this would make use of Websockets, in order to reduce the polling load on the server (as well as making it marginally easier to implement, as you don't have to manage polling).

I realized quickly that Ruby isn't really a great fit for having a large number of concurrent connections open at one time. Phoenix, however, is written in Elixir, so I can make use of the Erlang VM, which is quite good at long connections. It also seems like it could be greatly beneficial if all the chat data was stored separate from the main application database, which should also reduce load in the future.

#### The Problem

I want to be able to make this separation completely invisible to the user. They visit `www.example.com/chat`, and it loads all the relevant data in from `chat.example.com` and starts up the websockets, without requiring them to login to a separate service. I think using an `<iframe>` is probably the way to go about doing this.

My problem is sharing authentication and data between the two applications. The Rails app needs to be able to create conversations on the Phoenix app in response to certain events. The Phoenix app needs to know what user is currently authenticated into Rails, as well as general data about the user.

An OAuth flow with the Rails app as the ID provider seemed like a good fit at first, but I can't figure out a way for the Phoenix app to *automatically* be granted access. I also have some concerns about user records existing inside the Phoenix app—it should be aware of all users on the main application, so you can start a chat with a user even if they haven't ever opened chat.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? My intuition says that this is going to involve `window.postMessage` and some kind of token system, but I wanted to ask what the generally accepted way of doing this was before I accidentally created an insecure mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sharing the session isn't too hard, assuming you are running at least Rails 4.1 and using JSON serialization (default for apps created with >=4.1). A quick google search finds [PlugRailsCookieSessionStore](https://github.com/cconstantin/plug_rails_cookie_session_store), which accomplishes this.

For more information on what it takes to share a session between Rails and another language, Matt Aimonetti has an [excellent blog post](https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/11/30/sharing-rails-sessions-with-non-ruby-apps/) with detailed information.

Lastly, if you would prefer to stay entirely in Ruby, it's definitely doable. Ryan Stout discusses scalability around persistent connections in the [FAQ for Volt](http://docs.voltframework.com/en/index.html), which uses a persistent connection for every user. The article he links is also a great read. Just mentioning it to help you weigh the trade off of building a separate app in another language.